# Real time Notification and update

Tags: python, django, real-time

I want to implement  **real time notification and real time update** posts(**Tenders publication**) in my django project  i found this link [heroku post](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/3/17/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django)
And Some libraries but 
I don't know where should i start

More info : when a user publish a post this post appear for all other users at the same time this post published
Any ideas

Comment: This question is way too vague to produce any useful answers.

Comment: I want to implement real time update i.e when a user publish post this post appear for all other users at the same time post published @jordanm

Comment: Take a look at [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It can be helpfull here.

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel is future it will be added Django in `1.10` in the meantime you can add and test the channels using `pip install channels`

And here is the good examples take look [channels-examples](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/liveblog)

Comment: Thank you . You made my day 